# MongoDB Unable to $match object field returned by aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, match, lookup

I'm unable to filter the result of a lookup, by a field of an object aggregated from another collection.

I have the following aggregate function:

```
db.Persons.aggregate([
{ $lookup:
  {
    from: "Addresses",
    localField: "addressId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "address"
  }
},

{ $unwind: "$address" }
])
```

which returns something like:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "5dfa9", 
  "addressId" : ObjectId("5df95bd35a65a59142faa6be"), 
  "text" : "abc",
  "address" : 
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df95bd35a65a59142faa6be"), 
    "townId" : "3" 
  } 
}
```

When I add a `$match`:

```
db.Persons.aggregate([
  { $match: { address: { $elemMatch: { "townId": "3" } } } },
  { $lookup: { ... } },
  { $unwind: "$address" }
])
```

I get nothing. However, adding a match like this `{ $match: { text: "abc" } }` works perfectly.

**EDIT**: As suggested by @Adam Harrison in the comments, the `$match` statement needs to be added after the `$lookup` statement in order for it to work. Also, `{ $unwind: "$address" }` needed to be removed.

```
db.Persons.aggregate([
  { $lookup: { ... } },
  { $match: { address: { $elemMatch: { "townId": "3" } } } }
])
```

Comment: Seems like `$match` is your initial stage ? then there is no need to look into result of `$lookup` as issue should be prior to lookup, Can you please update this question to provide sample docs  from either of the collections with expected result..

Comment: how about `{ $match: { "FOOBAR.townId": "3" } }` ?

Comment: The `$match` stage needs to be placed after the `$lookup` in the pipeline, if you intend to filter on the results of the `$lookup`. It looks like the `Persons` collection doesn't have a `address.townId` field, meaning that the `$match` returns zero documents. Make sense?

Comment: Of course, it's the most obvious one! I think I've tried pretty much everything else. I only needed to remove the `{ $unwind: "$address" }`, then it worked as intended. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. @AdamHarrison Maybe you could add the answer below so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple Answer

The `$match` stage needs to be placed after the $lookup in the pipeline, if you intend to filter on the results of the `$lookup`. It looks like the Persons collection doesn't have an `address.townId` field, meaning that the `$match` returns zero documents.

### Better Answer

That said, you may want to start this operation on the `Addresses` collection and perform a `$lookup` to `Persons`, instead of the other way around.

Aggregation framework operations can take advantage of indexes when a [$match or $sort stage in placed at the beginning of the pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes). The current pipeline starts with a `$lookup`, so it will perform a full collection scan against the `Persons` collection where it may scan a large number of unnecessary documents and be very inefficient.

Starting the aggregation on `Addresses` will allow you to place an indexable `$match` stage at the start of the pipeline, and help to avoid scanning unnecessary `Person` documents:

```
db.Addresses.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { "townId" : 3 } }, // Can use index { townId: 1 } on Addresses
  { "$lookup": { "from" : "Persons", "localField" : "_id", "foreignField" : "addressId", "as" : "Persons" } },
  { "$unwind" : "$Persons" },
  ...
])
```

This aggregation is now effectively querying the `Persons` collection by `addressId`, so you should consider building the `{ addressId: 1 }` index on `Persons` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the additional input! I will definitely keep that in mind.